# Add Video or some custom block below media on product detail page

Tags: product, tabs, media

I want to add Video or some custom tabs on product detail page , how can i do it via my module

see screenshot :  [image]

I got one tutorial link : http://www.atwix.com/magento/insert-blocks/

but what to wirte to show it below media view more on product detail page

Answer (score 1):

http://templates-master.com/magento-easy-tabs.html

Use above extension to add custom tabs by using `attribute` and `static blocks` as well.

Hopefully this will work for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add video to product page in Magento below the product name. More importantly, you can do so without using any extension. This can be done by adding some code to the following file.

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```